# TI-84 programming parameter

Tags: ti-basic

Is it possible to execute a program within another program that requires parameters? (without inlining it)

E.g.

```
________________
 - PROGRAM:ADD
 - :Prompt A,B
 - :A+B>C
________________
 - PROGRAM:TEST
 - :For(I,0,20)
 - :Disp (prgmADD (I,I+1))
 - :End_________
```

Obviously this doesn't work the way it currently is, but I hope I made it clear what I'm getting at.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is a way to do that - you're basically asking to fake user input, which isn't supported.

The way I have gotten around it is preloading the variables by setting A and B to I, I+1. Then have another variable that you never touch in any program that is a flag letting the subprogram know it can skip input.

When the subprogram runs, it uses an if statment to check the flag variable. If it is set to a specific value you've chosen, it knows that it means it doesn't have to run the Prompt command because A and B are already set. After checking the value, it should reset the flag so that when you run it manually later it doesn't skip the prompt.

The specific convention I used was to have the last list in the system reserved for use by my programs. Each program knew to look at the list for parameters. That made it so I didn't have to worry about getting variable letters matched up between programs. So in this case the first element of the list could be 1 to signal that there are parameters to read. If it is 0, it uses prompt. Otherwise it looks at the second and third elements for the values of A and B. It clears the list when it is done with it, so the leftover data doesn't interfere with later runs.

Answer (score 9):

The conventional way to pass arguments is in a list through `Ans` like so:

```
________________
 - PROGRAM:ADD
 - :Ans(1)+Ans(2
________________
 - PROGRAM:TEST
 - :For(I,0,20
 - :{I,I+1
 - :prgmADD
 - :Disp Ans
 - :End
________________
```

Answer (score 2):

As Katie stated, there is no built in method for passing parameters between TI-Basic Programs. There is, however, a primitive method through which a single parameter can passed to a function.

An unevaluated expression can be held in one of the `Y-VARS` variables. Using this variable in your program will cause the expression contained within to be evaluated and the result to be returned. The interesting part of this is that `Y-VARS` variables can be passed a parameter which will be substituted for a single variable in the  body of the expression. The variable that it is substituted for depends on the `Y-VARS` variable you used. `Function` variables use `X`, `Parametric` use `T` and, `Polar` use `θ`.

---

This Sample program demonstrates what I have described.

```
:"XLog(X→Y1
:Disp Y1(10
:Disp Y1(5
```

When `Y1` is passed `10` as a parameter, all instance of `X` in `Y1` are replace with `10`. `Y1` is now equivalent to `10log(10`, or simply 10. The same affect is seen when passing `5` to `Y1`.

---

The obvious drawback of this workaround is that only one parameter can be passed. Other drawbacks include that you can only put standard calculator functions into one of the `Y-VARS` and that accessing `Y-VARS` comes with a significant overhead.