# how do I create a program using parameters using ti-basic 83

Tags: parameters, ti-basic

I am trying to create a simple program on my ti-84 plus that uses parameters when being called, like a function, but I have had no luck at finding documentation on the internet.

I am wanting to call the program like:
Simpleprogram(xyz,X), or something like that

Comment: Quoting from the [Wikipedia TI-BASIC article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TI-BASIC#Functions): "*Functions TI-83/84 (Z80) The Z80 version of TI-BASIC makes explicit "functions" like those in 68k impossible. However, all variables are global so functions can be emulated by setting variables, similar to arguments, before calling another program. Return values do not exist; the Return statement stops the current program and continues where the program was called.*"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TI-84 programming parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28369217/ti-84-programming-parameter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In 83/84 Basic? It is impossible, the best you can do is prompt the user for input or load the parameters into a list on the screen, press enter to load into Ans, and work with the data out of a list.